# How to use tail-recursive to implement a recursive function

Tags: recursion, scheme

> (replicate-to-length '(a b c) 8)

(a b c a b c a b)

> (replicate-to-length '(a b c) 2)

(a b)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? Also, what language is this? Not Haskell, anyway...

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes, which begs the question: why tag the question "Haskell"?

Comment: Is this problem can use the same way of that repeat problem?

Comment: It's scheme not haskell. I got mistake of the problem

Comment: thanks - I am sure some Schemers will help you very soon (I'm afraid my knowledge and interest in those are long gone ;) )

Comment: For information, if you get to Haskell at some stage, you could do: `replicateToLength xs n = let xs' = xs ++ xs' in take n xs'`.

Answer (score 2):

Well. you define a local procedure and make sure you don't shadow the original argument so that you can us it instead of the empty list.

```
(define (replicate-to-length x i)
  (define (replicate-to-length-aux cx i)
    ...)
  ;; call helper
  (replicate-to-length-aux x i))
```

Or you can lambda lift it:

```
(define (replicate-to-length-aux x cx i)
  ...)

(define (replicate-to-length x i)
  (replicate-to-length-aux x x i))
```

Of course I guess this is just to learn. I would have done something like this:

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base) 
        (only (srfi :1) circular-list take))

(define (replicate-to-length x i) 
  (take (apply circular-list x) i))
```

Comment: @唐笙凱 The two first just shows you how you can use a helper procedure (just like you question asked for), but it doesn't implement the procedure itself. You need to replace `...` with your implementation. The last example is a full implementation that makes a circular list out of the argument, thus `(a b) ; ==> (a b a b ...)` with infinite length, then takes `i` elements from it. Both of those procedures are defined in SRFI-1 as you can see from the import statement.

Comment: import: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier  ~~ whats this

Comment: @唐笙凱 Pehaps the implementation of your choice is a R5RS. Then you need to check with their documentation if they have included SRFI-1 and if not you can use  its reference implementation link in the [spec](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)

Comment: R5RS is necessary, and I dont understand how to use its referece implement. And thanks for your answer

Comment: @唐笙凱 And you have checked with the implementaions documenttion that it doesn't include SRFI-1? Which Scheme implementation are you using?

Comment: I use R5RS, it doesnt include SRFI-1

Comment: @唐笙凱 R5RS is a standard, not an implementation. Eg. Chicken Scheme is a R5RS implementation.  Gambit is another. See the difference? Both of the mention implementations has SRFI-1.